# jquery message displayed and disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

Im currently working with jQuery and SocketIO and and i want to connect two events at the same time.

1. My form has a warning message all the time being displayed:

`<div class="ui warning large message" title='networkNameWarning' id="networkNameWarning" style="word-wrap: break-word; display: block"> text </div>`

and the submission button:

`<button class="ui fluid teal button" id="#submit-form-button" type="submit" style="margin-top: 1rem"> Submit </button>`

I tried different approaches but, how to disable the button when the message is displayed? and vice-versa if the message change to display:none remove the disabled class ..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Better solutions in this case is  create application state (plain Object)  and on event change  it and  then using it  do  changes in DOM (e.g. disable/enable button, hide/show message).

Comment: sorry can you give me a little bit of detail. I was thinking something like this as example but i think something is missing:

` if (($msgWarning).css('display') === 'block') {
    submitFormButton.attr("disabled", 'disabled');
} else {
    submitFormButton.removeClass('disabled');
}`

Comment: in your code snippet you  try add attribute "disabled" but then you remove class disabled. 
Also you can try to use submitFormButton.prop("disabled",true); and submitFormButton.prop("disabled",false); for enabling and disabling button